# How can I save a double in values folder on android

Tags: android, xml, double, hardcode

I don't want to hardcode a double, so I wanted to put it in the values folder, either in a new XML or in the strings.xml

I know it exists:

```
<string name="a_string">my string</string>
<bool name="is_a_bool">true </bool>
<string-array name="string_array">
        <item>ítem 1</item>
        <item>ítem 2</item>
</string-array>
```

etcetera.

but how can I do to add a double?, like this:

```
<double name="a_double">-20.50</double>
```

cause I want to use it here:

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal|numberSigned"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/txtLatitude"
            android:text="@.../a_double" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put your double in a string:

```
<string name="a_double">-20.50</string>
```

And you it in layout as this:

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal|numberSigned"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/txtLatitude"
            android:text="@string/a_double" />
```

Please visit Android developer website, there's no double resources:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html

Comment: yes, that's what I finally did. But was wondering if there was any XML value for doubles, cause it does exist for integer :)

Answer (score 0):

No you have to set your any data type value in Sting formate :

```
<string name="price">2.6555</string>
```

Whenever you use the value just **Parse** it in the original data type.